# How create custom embeddable html form as copy-paste plugin so my clients insert it in their Webs and their users can use my Web service

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services

My Web service is a reservation center for restaurants where We offer our clients  an administration for reservations.

We I need our clients  generate forms, something like  HTML + CSS + Javascript code ready to copy-paste in their Webs.

Currently We only offer a simple HTML form code generated from PHP in a very simple way after our client  customize some colors. 
But this form is generated without dynamic interactivity, no javascript.

We want distribute a more dynamic code.
For example, We want add datepickers or some validations in javascript.
The Datepicker needs javascript library,  doesn't it?

We need  ideas on how currently this is being done in other services.

Do you think is better distribute inside iframes? Currently We distribute form element raw  html.
Could be better libraries linked as absolute URL to the reservation center?
Where are lost in a lot of considerations.

Has anyone had to do something about this and can give us some guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are allowed to use external services you could embed Google Forms.

Comment: Thank you ,  I  do not know this possibility  and  I'll start reading about this   Very happy because this hint.